# Are rpm packages for CentOS-7 compatible with CentOS-8?

Tags: centos

Someone said they weren't, but I just pointed my CentOS-8 to CentOS-7 repos and was able to install a few packages just fine (they aren't found in 8 repos). Can there be hidden obstacles down that path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend against doing this. It can cause conflicts with packages and their dependencies. If a package with dependencies is installed, then it's going to pull the dependencies from the CentOS repo. It's possible that these will be older versions or different packages entirely that will conflict with packages from the CentOS 8 repos. This has the potential to render the system unusable.

Rather than installing the packages from the repos of an older version of the OS, research them to see if the names have changed and install those. If you have confirmed that they aren't available, download the source code and build them. These methods don't cause the potential conflicts.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the version-differrence between the libraries that were used to compile the packages and the ones that are installed on your system.
So some will work and some will not. And some might have sideeffects...